# Understanding graph generate by ANTS profiler

Tags: c#-4.0, redgate, red-gate-ants

I am profiling memory usgae in my application using ANTS profiler and it shows that large amount of memory is held up in generation 2 by Excell cell object. Application is using EPPlus library to generate excel file.

I am attaching some of the graph generated by the tool. **I am not sure how to drill further to figure out which object is holding reference & eating up memory. Please provide your suggestion on how to drill further into the graph.**

[image: Summary Chart]

[image: Instance graph_1]

[image: Instance Graph_2]

[image]

The problem is: This graph again points tp same object. I think I am not using this tool properly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly- only you, as the developer, know if those Excell objects should be in memory or not (how would an outside observer know whether these were cached objects or not, for example)? You could present info on whether Dispose had been called on those objects perhaps.

Secondly- do you see where it has given you a warning of Large Object hap fragmentation? I'd investigate that first.

Comment: Thank you for reply. looking at the first grpah I have attached it says Largest fragment is around 41.17 MB (27.4% of free memory). I want to understand is that too much? Should I be worried about this number? If yes, what should be my next move? Thank you

Comment: All I can say right now is - *probably*  not. Keep observing what happens *over time*. If memory does not creep up *over time* you're OK but if it does- start thinking in terms of a leak. The tool will tell you why objects are still in memory (when they perhaps shouldn't be). It's more of an art than a science though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the two snapshots you have taken (from summary screen) I am lacking context of the workflow for each snapshot, So I am going to make some assumptions:

Snapshot 1: is prior to you creating an Excel file.
Snapshot 2: is after you have created the Excel file and you deem this action completed.

Firstly I would recommend you slightly adjust your workflow and do the following snapshots.

Snapshot 1: taken prior to creating an Excel file.

Snapshot 2/3: Depends on the applications workflow; if you create data (can view it etc), then create a file after the fact from this data then take a snapshot after data generation and then another after file creation.

Final snapshot: Take one final snapshot - this is good practice to get a better feel of what is in memory after a completed workflow as it allows for clearing of finalizer queue.

There is going to be no answer here as it is hard to do this from a few screenshots - just advice - I have no knowledge of your application, and making assumptions about your desired memory usage like caching of data etc.

(a) Using the Instance Categorizor view with Categorized References selected you need to start at top(only) reference chain and work right to left. Again making assumptions (simplistic ones) look beyond nodes that are part of the Excel library and see what class is referencing it. 
At this point this will either give you enough to look for that reference in code (b) or a starting to point to explore deeper (c). (a) if you think this reference chain(right to left path) is not worth pursuing then move to the next one down. With the Instance Categorizor view you work Right-Left, Top-Botton.

(b) If you have source code you can rght-click on a node and browse to the class in Visual Studio. Or just go there yourself :>

(c) By exploring a reference chain from (a) deeper I mean to using the link "Show the instances on this path" then making a judgment from the displayed metrics (size, Distance from GC root) choose an instance of the class to explore in more details. This will take you to the Instance Retention Graph which shows you the reference chain for that instance in more details. Pay attention to tool tips here, coloured regions and the type of node all mean various things. See my links below.

I think what is clear from this answer is you would likely benefit from looking at the AMP documentation since there is a lot to learn and I have only taken an extremely high level walk through the application with you and I have made many (far to many) assumptions.

See links for some help:

[Class view filters](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/amp_filtering_overview.htm&toc=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/toc1286240.htm)

[Instance Categorizor](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/amp_3_categorizer.htm&toc=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/toc1286233.htm)

[Instance retention graph](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/amp_5_retention.htm&toc=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/toc1286233.htm)

[Large object heap fragmentation tips](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/Content?p=ANTS%20Memory%20Profiler&c=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/amp_loh_frag.htm&toc=ANTS_Memory_Profiler/help/7.0/toc1286225.htm) <- As pointed out by other poster.

[Red Gate's learning portal for the Memory profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/video/) <- Perhaps look at Videos and the Technical Papers sections

I hope that gets you started.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply and explaining all the things. The first image is just a summary image which tells me that after file is generated ExcelCell is using 61 MB. The next 3 images are part of object graph which is spiltted into 3 (Right to Left). The problem is, it is showing same objects after i drill further (from right to left). I was hoping system will point out final object which is holding all the references. just wanted to check If I am going in the right direction or not.